# Edit Ng-Repeat inline with REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest, slim, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been at this for awhile now but in short I am making a UI that allows our users to modify a MySQL DB using an Angular frontend and Slim PHP to serve up the REST.

I continue to get an error stating that 'firstName' is not defined as a column and I cant seem to figure out why.  I believe it has something to do with the way the ng-repeat works and how I can assign / call objects inside of it but I am stuck!

Here is the HTML, App.js and index.php - The code is a little hacked up but I want to edit the rows in-line.

Any knowledge is much appreciated as I have just started using Angular and REST this year!

### List.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th> 
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Address 1</th>      
                    <th>Address 2</th>      
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>State</th> 
                    <th>Zip</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="referral in referrals | filter:query | limitTo:limitBy | orderBy:lastName">
                <tr >
                    <td>{{referral.ID}}</td>
                    <td>
<!--                        <span id="firstName" data-ng-hide="editMode">{{referral.firstName}}</span>-->
                        <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{referral.firstName}}</span>
                        <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" ng-model="referral.firstName"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{referral.lastName}}</span>
                        <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" ng-model="referral.lastName"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{referral.address1}}</span>
                        <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="referral.address1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{referral.address2}}</span>
                        <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="referral.address2"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{referral.city}}</span>
                        <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="referral.city"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{referral.state}}</span>
                        <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="referral.state"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{referral.zipCode}}</span>
                        <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="referral.zipCode"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" data-ng-hide="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = true; editAppKey(entry)" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
                        <button type="submit" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false; saveField(referral)" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                        <button type="submit" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false; cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

### App.js

```
app.controller('viewController', function($resource, $scope, $location, $route, $routeParams) {

    $scope.title = 'Endo Admin';

    $scope.query = {};
    $scope.queryBy = 'lastName';
    $scope.limitBy = '50';  

    var Referrals = $resource('http://pdgrosit02v/endoAdmin/app/api/referrals'); 

    $scope.referrals = Referrals.query();

    $scope.newField = {};
    $scope.editing = false;

    $scope.editAppKey = function(field) {
        $scope.editing = $scope.referrals.indexOf(field);
        $scope.newField = angular.copy(field);  
    }

    $scope.saveField = function(index) {
//        if ($scope.editing !== false) {

//        var Referral = $resource(('http://pdgrosit02v/endoAdmin/app/api/referral/'+ index.ID));
//
//        $scope.referral = Referral.get();
//        
          $scope.referral = $scope.newField;
//            $scope.editing = false;

            var ReferralPut = $resource(('http://pdgrosit02v/endoAdmin/app/api/referral/'+ index.ID), {}, { update: { method: 'PUT'}} );

            ReferralPut.update($scope.referral, function() {
                    // success
                    $location.path('/endoadmin');                     
                }, function() {
                    // error
                    console.log(error);
                });      
    };     
});
```

### index.php

```
<?php

require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

use Slim\Slim;

$app = new Slim();

$app->get('/referrals', 'getReferrals');

$app->get('/referral/:id',  'getReferral');

$app->put('/referral/:id', 'updateReferral');

$app->run();

function updateReferral($id) {
    $referral = Slim::getInstance()->request()->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($referral, true);
    $sql = "UPDATE endo_referral SET firstName=:first_Name, lastName=:last_Name WHERE ID=$id";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":first_Name", $data['firstName']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":last_Name", $data['lastName']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($data); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error from Slim or Angular?

Comment: I get this as the response to my PUT request

""{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'firstName' cannot be null}}""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the $scope.saveField function, you should use the passed-in referral. Instead of

```
...
ReferralPut.update($scope.referral, function() {
                    // success
                    $location.path('/endoadmin');                     
                }, function() {
                    // error
                    console.log(error);
                });
...
```

Looking at your code, it looks like this needs to be:

```
ReferralPut.update(index, function() {
                    // success
                    $location.path('/endoadmin');                     
                }, function() {
                    // error
                    console.log(error);
                 });
```

The $scope.saveField function is passed the current referral in the `index` field.  $scope.referral is undefined in the saveField function.

There may be other issues, but this was the one that stood out the most.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you!

I knew it had to be something simple!  That was exactly what it was, now my system is working inline properly!

Thanks again!